# Is there an efficient way to focus to the next textformfield? (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, performance, textfield

I have an app with almost 300 textfields and I been using the autofocus and textinputaction properties to go to the next textfield. And it works well for the textfields with a normal keyboard. But when I come to the next part of the form with a numeric keyboard this properties become unreliable and don't always focus the next textfield. I have heard that using Focusnode class would be a a solution but that would emply to make 300 focus nodes and implement them.

I wonder if one of you knows another way to focus to next field in a more reliable and efficient way.

Thanks for your answers!

Examples:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZjBz.gif
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEOnw.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXeGf.png

Answer (score 0):

textInputAction: TextInputAction.next
Should work just fine

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can solve it.

```
Form(
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        TextFormField(
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.next, // Keyboard with Next arrow
          autofocus: true, // Place cursor on this field at start up
          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "First field"),
        ),
        TextFormField(
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Second field"),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I already tried that. And it didn't work with me. I had to use focusnodes and now it works perfectly. Thanks nonetheless for your attention!